# I have IronPython set up so it can find needed imports, but when running I get an exception "No module named warnings"

Tags: python, c#, .net, warnings, ironpython

As the title says I get a "no module named _____" exception when running a script through IronPython. The module that it can't find is warnings. What is strange, however, is that I do not import warnings or use any of its functions in the python script. Warnings is a default class I know, but if that's the case IronPython should have access directly to it right? I tried making a test script with all of the imports I use but the actual code was just hello world and that worked fine. Can I add some path to help IronPython find warnings somehow? If not, why is it throwing this error in this instance?

Here is what I have so far in terms of paths:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\FileName\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1");
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\PythonScript\PythonScriptFolderLocation");
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\PythonScript\PythonScriptFolderLocationEnv\Lib");
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\PythonScript\PythonScriptFolderLocationEnv\Lib\site-packages");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
var script = "C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\PythonScript\\PythonScriptFolderLocation\\run.py";
```